# Making Java 8 groupingBy-based map "null safe" when accessing the stream of a null group

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Java 8 here. I have the following POJOs:

```
public enum VehicleType {
  Car,
  Motorcycle,
  Scooter,
  Skateboard
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Driver {
  private String uuid;
  private Long numYearsDriving;
  private VehicleType vehicleType;
}
```

Now I have the following code that takes a `List<Driver>` and organizes them onto a `Map<VehicleType,List<Driver>` where the keys are the different types of vehicles we have, and each value is the "sub-list" (of the original list) of all `Drivers` for those vehicle types:

```
List<Driver> allDrivers = getSomehow();

Map<VehicleType,List<Driver>> driversByVehicleType = allDrivers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Driver::getVehicleType));
```

So far, so good, I *think*. Now I want to inspect that map and fetch all the drivers of either scooters or skateboards. My best attempt:

```
List<Driver> scooterSkateboarders = Stream
      .concat(
          driversByVehicleType.get(VehicleType.Scooter).stream(),
          driversByVehicleType.get(VehicleType.Skateboard).stream())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

...compiles, however, it throws a `NullPointerException` if `allDrivers` **does not** contain any Scooter/Skateboard drivers to begin with. So I ask: how to make my code "null safe" in the event that `allDrivers` only contains, say, `Car` drivers?

Comment: `driversByVehicleType.getOrDefault(VehicleType.Scooter, Collections.emptyList())`

Comment: That gives me all scoot drivers, but not both scoot **and** skateboarders. I need both in the same fell swoop, I'm not interested in making one list of scooter drivers, a second list of skateboarders, and then merging them together, unless thats the **only** way...

Comment: Do you need the intermediate `Map`? Otherwise you can just filter the original stream?

Comment: Added another alternative yo my answer: directly streaming the `entrySet`, and filter by `Entry::getKey`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *don't* need the intermediate `Map`, you can filter the original stream:

```
List<Driver> scooterSkateboarders = allDrivers.stream()
    .filter(driver -> EnumSet.of(Scooter, Skateboard).contains(driver.getVehicleType()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you *do* need the intermediate `Map`:

```
List<Driver> scooterSkateboarders = Stream
    .concat(
        driversByVehicleType.getOrDefault(VehicleType.Scooter, Collections.emptyList()).stream(),
        driversByVehicleType.getOrDefault(VehicleType.Skateboard, Collections.emptyList()).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or alternatively, immediately stream the `entrySet`

```
List<Driver> scooterSkateboarders = driversByVehicleType.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> EnumSet.of(Scooter, Skateboard).contains(e.getKey()))
    .map(Entry::getValue)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The last one would be my preferred solution.

Comment: One can combine `.map(Entry::getValue).flatMap(List::stream)` to `flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream())` and also initialise the `Set` only once instead of for every element in `filter`.

Comment: I know. I tend to separate map from flatmap to keep it a bit more declarative (matter of personal taste). I kept the definition of set inline for the sake of brevity, but in reality you would indeed store this in variable...

Comment: @Naman you can also omit the set and replace `e -> EnumSet.of(Scooter, Skateboard).contains(e.getKey())` with a simple `e -> e.getKey()==Scooter || e.getKey()==Skateboard` for this scenario with only two keys…

Answer (score 1):

Using Java-9 and above you can implicitly use the filtering logic as you groupBy using `Collectors.filtering` such as:

```
Set<VehicleType> validVehicles = Set.of(VehicleType.Scooter, VehicleType.Skateboard);
Map<VehicleType, List<Driver>> driversByVehicleType = allDrivers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Driver::getVehicleType,
                Collectors.filtering(d -> validVehicles.contains(d.getVehicleType()),
                        Collectors.toList())));
```

This would ensure empty list in values where none qualifies the filter while grouping by the type.